# 2 Different InitialContextFacory implementation in one Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, jndi

I have a legacy web-app that uses its own implementation of InitialContextFacory and Context that uses some own xml file format where resources are defined.
This application is deployed to a Tomcat (6.0.29).

To set the InitialContextFacory impl system property is set to for the tomcat:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=mypack.MyContextFactoryImpl
```

Now I want to deploy an other application to the same tomcat that loads resources from context.xml. But I got class not found exception for mypack.MyContextFactoryImpl, what is fine since my other app does not knows this class, and the environment variable that sets the InitialContextFactory is global, thus applies on all deployed application.

So how can I resolve this problem, thus specifying the initialContextFactory just for the first application within the tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat Configuration are two types

**Global level**

specify your configurations in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`

**per-web-application**

per-web-application context XML file `(META-INF/context.xml)`.

for more details reffer this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Comment: Hi, thx for reply,but, what I don't what to do is change the legacy application. Where the InitialContextFactory is already different from that one the tomcat provides, so I can't event access this was the resources that tomcat provides. Here is not the problem to configure the resources per application, the problem is to configure the resource provide per application...